# Atmega328 to SD card issues

Tags: arduino, atmega, sd, 3.3v

I am working on a board that includes an Atmega328 which needs to read data from an SD card. I am having problems. Here is a diagram:

[image]

I believe the issue may stem from the voltage divider that is connected to The hex converter  (74HC4050D) and the micro SD card. However I have tried removing that and connecting a regulated 3.3V signal in it place and it still does not work. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Hex converter" isn't a part number. Please be specific.

Comment: Ah, that old chestnut again... **You can't use a voltage divider as a power source**

Comment: I updated the question to include the part number.

Comment: Have you checked that you haven't killed either the SD card or the 4050 chip by driving signals into it with a voltage divider as a power supply?

Comment: Also, add a small series resistance to the inputs of the 4050 to limit the current.

Comment: @TannerEwing  Is there a reason for not running the entire circuit off +3.3V ?  That would eliminate the need for level shifters and additional regulator.

Comment: @TannerEwing  can you show me your fixed schematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a separate 3 volt linear regulator for the SD card. Use one that has an ENABLE input, because to reset the SD card (after an error), you need to power down the card and pull all the signals to zero. You also need a level shifter to translate between the 5 volt AVR and the 3 volt SD card signals, although even resistor dividers can be used for that. If you connect PB4 like you have, be careful not to drive 5 volts from PB4 by accident. At least use a series resistor as a rudimentary safety feature if you don't want to invest in a proper level shifter IC.